# An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, heroku

I am getting this error when I use the command `git push heroku master`.

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 126, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (110/110), done.
Writing objects: 100% (126/126), 36.61 KiB, done.
Total 126 (delta 19), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Installing rake (10.0.3)
       Installing i18n (0.6.4)
       Installing multi_json (1.6.1)
       Installing activesupport (3.2.12)
       Installing builder (3.0.4)
       Installing activemodel (3.2.12)
       Installing erubis (2.7.0)
       Installing journey (1.0.4)
       Installing rack (1.4.5)
       Installing rack-cache (1.2)
       Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
       Installing hike (1.2.1)
       Installing tilt (1.3.5)
       Installing sprockets (2.2.2)
       Installing actionpack (3.2.12)
       Installing mime-types (1.21)
       Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
       Installing treetop (1.4.12)
       Installing mail (2.4.4)
       Installing actionmailer (3.2.12)
       Installing arel (3.0.2)
       Installing tzinfo (0.3.37)
       Installing activerecord (3.2.12)
       Installing activeresource (3.2.12)
       Installing coffee-script-source (1.6.1)
       Installing execjs (1.4.0)
       Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Installing rack-ssl (1.3.3)
       Installing json (1.7.7)
       Installing rdoc (3.12.2)
       Installing thor (0.17.0)
       Installing railties (3.2.12)
       Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Installing jquery-rails (2.2.1)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Installing rails (3.2.12)
       Installing sass (3.2.7)
       Installing sass-rails (3.2.6)
       Installing sqlite3 (1.3.7)
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
       necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
       details.  You may need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
       --enable-local
       --disable-local
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_19fmy6g68v7he/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_19fmy6g68v7he/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occurred whenter code hereile installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:whispering-taiga-7415.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:whispering-taiga-7415.git'
```

Comment: There have been a rather large amount of similar questions asked already. Please search those before asking again. If they don't solve your issue, please provide additional information on what you have tried.

Comment: i went through most of the forums regarding this but was not able to solve the problem.... i have installed sqlite3 on my system. @holger just

Comment: tried git status on terminal and it gave me this                       # On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
# modified:   .DS_Store

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use sqlite3 with Heroku. By default, Heroku's Cedar stack uses Postgresql. You need to wrap your `sqlite3` gem in a development group and have `pg` in your Gemfile.

```
group :development, :test do 
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

gem 'pg'
```

Make sure to run bundle install again after editing the Gemfile so you can push to heroku

Comment: so you mean i should  edit that gem file?

Comment: Yeah, the Gemfile is for you to edit. That's where all your libraries (gems in ruby) are specified.

Comment: Should I remove anything from the gem file? Or just copy-paste this into that file?

Comment: You can paste that into the file. Just make sure you don't have the gem 'sqlite3q' outside of the block. It seems you'd benefit from reading this. http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: thanks leo...im following the same book. thats why i am having the issue.

Comment: Make sure you are committing the right changes to heroku.

Comment: I put this in exactly as stated, did bundle install. But still got the error "Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling."

Comment: was this from heroku or local?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku generally doesn't support SQLite as a database engine, mostly because they don't give your app write access to a local file system during runtime as would be required for SQLite.

Instead, you should use PostgreSQL (with the `pg` gem) as a database engine as recommended by Heroku.

Comment: how to do that....it will look like a dumb question to you but i am new into development. So need help. Thank you in advance @holger just

Comment: I removed sqlite3 and just used 'pg' but when I pushed I still got Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: You then still have a reference to sqlite in your `Gemfile` which is thus still installed. As said above, ensure that you remove that. It could also be that some other gem you have there has sqlite as a hard dependency. You can have a look at the `Gemfile.lock` to check that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Open the Gemfile.lock and scroll down to sqlite3 (1.3.x) under 'specs:'
- Make sure it appears only as sqlite3 (1.3.x) with no extra jazz.
- If any extra tags such as "-x86-mingw32" is displayed then delete it.
- Run Bundle Install.
- Then try pushing Heroku master.

Worked for me.