# Unable to push Rails Bootstrap project to Heroku

Tags: heroku, railsapps, learn-ruby-on-rails

I'm finished up with the [railsapps.org](http://railsapps.github.io/) tutorial on [Rails and Bootstrap](http://railsapps.github.io/twitter-bootstrap-rails.html).  I am not able to deploy it to Heroku though.  My code is exactly as the tutorial, and I followed the directions exactly in the "Deploy" chapter, but when I run `git push heroku master` I get the errors below.  Any ideas what is wrong?

Regards,
Jeff

```
$ git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 136, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (113/113), done.
Writing objects: 100% (136/136), 27.95 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 136 (delta 35), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.1.1
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
   Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
   Using json (1.8.1)
   Installing minitest (5.3.3)
   Installing rake (10.3.1)
   Installing i18n (0.6.9)
   Installing thread_safe (0.3.3)
   Installing builder (3.2.2)
   Installing mime-types (1.25.1)
   Installing rack (1.5.2)
   Installing erubis (2.7.0)
   Installing polyglot (0.3.4)
   Installing coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
   Installing arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
   Installing execjs (2.0.2)
   Installing sass (3.2.19)
   Installing multipart-post (2.0.0)
   Installing mini_portile (0.5.3)
   Installing thor (0.19.1)
   Installing oauth (0.4.7)
   Installing multi_xml (0.5.5)
   Using bundler (1.5.2)
   Installing multi_json (1.10.0)
   Installing hike (1.2.3)
   Installing high_voltage (2.1.0)
   Installing tilt (1.4.1)
   Installing tzinfo (1.1.0)
   Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
   /tmp/build_a6d6f6f3-1b58-4344-8c47-ff3f4229b149/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb
   checking for sqlite3.h... no
   sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
   'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
   and check your shared library search path (the
   location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
   *** extconf.rb failed ***
   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
   libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
   need configuration options.
   Provided configuration options:
   --with-opt-dir
   --without-opt-dir
   --with-opt-include
   --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
   --with-opt-lib
   --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
   --with-make-prog
   --without-make-prog
   --srcdir=.
   --curdir
   --ruby=/tmp/build_a6d6f6f3-1b58-4344-8c47-ff3f4229b149/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
   --with-sqlite3-dir
   --without-sqlite3-dir
   --with-sqlite3-include
   --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
   --with-sqlite3-lib
   --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
   --enable-local
   --disable-local
   extconf failed, exit code 1
   Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_a6d6f6f3-1b58-4344-8c47-ff3f4229b149/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9 for inspection.
   Results logged to /tmp/build_a6d6f6f3-1b58-4344-8c47-ff3f4229b149/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.9/gem_make.out
   Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
   Installing rdoc (4.1.1)
   Installing treetop (1.4.15)
   An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.9'` succeeds before bundling.
   Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
   Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
   Using json (1.8.1)
   Installing minitest (5.3.3)
   Installing rake (10.3.1)
   Installing i18n (0.6.9)
   Installing thread_safe (0.3.3)
   Installing builder (3.2.2)
   Installing mime-types (1.25.1)
   Installing rack (1.5.2)
   Installing erubis (2.7.0)
   Installing polyglot (0.3.4)
   Installing coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
   Installing arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
   Installing execjs (2.0.2)
   Installing sass (3.2.19)
   Installing multipart-post (2.0.0)
   Installing mini_portile (0.5.3)
   Installing thor (0.19.1)
   Installing oauth (0.4.7)
   Installing multi_xml (0.5.5)
   Using bundler (1.5.2)
   Installing multi_json (1.10.0)
   Installing hike (1.2.3)
   Installing high_voltage (2.1.0)
   Installing tilt (1.4.1)
   Installing tzinfo (1.1.0)

   Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

   /tmp/build_a6d6f6f3-1b58-4344-8c47-ff3f4229b149/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb
   checking for sqlite3.h... no
   sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
   'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
   and check your shared library search path (the
   location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
   *** extconf.rb failed ***
   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
   libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
   need configuration options.

   Provided configuration options:
   --with-opt-dir
   --without-opt-dir
   --with-opt-include
   --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
   --with-opt-lib
   --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
   --with-make-prog
   --without-make-prog
   --srcdir=.
   --curdir
   --ruby=/tmp/build_a6d6f6f3-1b58-4344-8c47-ff3f4229b149/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
   --with-sqlite3-dir
   --without-sqlite3-dir
   --with-sqlite3-include
   --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
   --with-sqlite3-lib
   --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
   --enable-local
   --disable-local

   extconf failed, exit code 1

   Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_a6d6f6f3-1b58-4344-8c47-ff3f4229b149/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9 for inspection.
   Results logged to /tmp/build_a6d6f6f3-1b58-4344-8c47-ff3f4229b149/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.9/gem_make.out
   Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
   Installing rdoc (4.1.1)
   Installing treetop (1.4.15)
   An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.9'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:rails-bootstrap-test.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:rails-bootstrap-test.git'
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the book, your Gemfile should look like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.1'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'activerecord-tableless'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'google_drive'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'simple_form'
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', :platforms=>[:mri_21]
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rails_layout'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Make sure `gem 'sqlite3'` is in the development group. SQLite is not supported on Heroku so you don't want Heroku trying to install it.

Comment: I cut and pasted the gemfile from the tutorial, and it looks exactly as above.  I actually saw that and remembered from the learn rails book that SQLite3 wasn't supported, but I'm completely bewildered since it seems like heroku is trying to load that Gem even though it shows up in the development group.  Yesterday I pushed the learn-rails app up to heroku and it went off without a hitch...

Answer (score 1):

This has been a problem for others as well...including myself.  I solved it by making sure sqlite3 was only in the development group and *pushing to github again to update any changes*.

Here are some links where it seems others have commented on this problem:

- [An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550624/an-error-occurred-while-installing-sqlite3-1-3-7-and-bundler-cannot-continue)
- [Errors of pushing rails app to Heroku error occurred while installing sqlite3, and Bundler cannot continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548040/errors-of-pushing-rails-app-to-heroku-error-occurred-while-installing-sqlite3-a)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so weird...  I ended up destroying the Heroku app and recreating it.  That solved the problem it seems.